# RESideMenu and Navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I'm using this for a side menu in my app: https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu

I'm having some issues to implement it in my own way. The samples work fine, but I have problem to make it work over my app navigation.

I would like to have access to this menu over my whole application. I'll show you how I integrate it.

Here is my HomeViewController `viewDidLoad` which is also my rootViewController

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];

LeftSideMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [[LeftSideMenuViewController alloc] init];

RESideMenu *sideMenuViewController = [[RESideMenu alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController
                                                                leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                               rightMenuViewController:nil];


[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

sideMenuViewController.delegate = self;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController = sideMenuViewController;
```

From this controller I perform a `show segue` to navigate to the next ViewController which works like a `UITabViewController`, cf. : https://github.com/robbdimitrov/RDVTabBarController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"side_menu_left_not_focused_icon"]
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(presentLeftMenuViewController:)];


UIViewController *sessionViewController = [[SessionTableViewController alloc] init];

UIViewController *firstNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                               initWithRootViewController:sessionViewController];

UIViewController *searchViewController = [[SearchViewController alloc] init];

UIViewController *secondNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                               initWithRootViewController:searchViewController];

[self setViewControllers:@[firstNavigationController, secondNavigationController]];
}
```

And finally here is my `LeftSideMenuViewController` where I want to perform my action:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        /*Here is where I want to pop to my HomeViewController*/
        [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

In the project sample they perform this action :

```
[self.sideMenuViewController setContentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[ViewController alloc] init]]
                                                     animated:YES];
```

I just want to get back to my `HomeViewController` by popping the current one. But obviously `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` does not have any effect.